# Haskell: Understanding the bind operator (>>=) for Monads

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

I have the following function:

```
parse :: String -> Maybe Token
```

And I am trying to implement the following function:

```
maketokenlist :: String -> Maybe [Token]
```

The function returns Nothing if there is a token that was not able to be parsed (i.e. parse returns Nothing if the token is not an integer or an arithmetic operator), otherwise it returns a list of Tokens.

As Maybe is an instance of the Monad type class, I have the following approach:

```
maketokenlist str =  return (words str) >>= parse
```

I convert the string into a list of individual tokens (e.g. "2 3 +" becomes ["2","3","+"] , and then map the parse function over each string in the list.

Since the Monad instance for lists is defined as:

```
instance Monad [] where
   return x = [x] 
   xs >>= f = concat (map f xs)
   fail _ = []
```

However, say that I had the list of strings [2, 3, "+", "a"] and after mapping parse over each element using >>= I get [Just 2, Just 3, Just (+), Nothing], as "a" cannot be parsed. Is there a way to make the function maketokenlist return Nothing using just the >>= operator? Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: `[2, 3, "+", "a"]`, This is neither a list, nor any construct that makes any sense in Haskell. A list must be made of a single type like so, `[a]`. So you could have `[2,3]` or `["+","a"]`. Rethink the problem, and try again.

Comment: `return` wraps its argument in a monad, and `>>=` immediately unwraps it. So `return (words str) >>= parse` is equivalent to `parse (words str)`. Is there a reason you need to use `>>=`, instead of, say, `maketokenlist str = map parse (words str)`?

Answer (score 4):

If `parse :: String -> Maybe Token`, then:

```
traverse parse :: [String] -> Maybe [Token]
```

This version of `traverse` (which I have specialized to act on lists as the `Traversable` instance and `Maybe` as the `Applicative` instance) may indeed be implemented using `(>>=)`:

```
listMaybeTraverse parse [] = pure []
listMaybeTraverse parse (s:ss) =
    parse s >>= \token ->
    listMaybeTraverse parse ss >>= \tokens ->
    pure (token:tokens)
```

I have chosen the names `parse`, `s`, and `token` to show the correspondence with your planned usage, but of course it will work for any appropriately-typed functions, not just `parse`.

The instance of `Monad` for lists does not make an appearance in this code.